# How to work with the service table layer_style in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server

Help me please.

Current versions: 
QGIS 2.14
Sql Server 2012

How to save a layer style in a service table layer_styles?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to version 2.18 you should see the option to save the style to the database (mssql):

[image]